# Remove Object from Json Object

Tags: angularjs, json, foreach

I was looking for solutions from Google and from this site. But I did not find the right answer for me. I have a json object:

```
$scope.jsonObject = {
    "Card":{
          "type":"menu",
          "options":["option1","option2"],
          "name":"With card",
          "next":{
               "operations":{
                   "type":"menu",
                   "options":["option1","option2"],
                   "name":"Card Operations",
                   "next":{ 
                        "balance":{ 
                           "type":"transaction",
                           "options":["option1","option2"],
                           "name":"Get Balance",
                           "next":null           
                         },
                         "history":{ 
                           "type":"transaction",
                           "options":["option1","option2"],
                           "name":"History Card",
                           "next":null           
                         }
                   }

              }  
        }
   }
}
```

This is a template menu, From this menu I need create new menu with angular foreach:

```
$scope.sortMenu = {};
function sortObject(menu){
  angular.foreach(menu, function(key,value){
    if(key == "card"){
       $scope.sortMenu = menu;
    } 
    if(key == "history"){
       // I need delete object "history" from $scope.sortMenu    
    }
    sortObject(value.next);
  });
}
sortObject($scope.jsonObject);
```

### How to write for delete "history" object from new menu?

Thanks, for all answers. Now, I change the question a bit. This is the $scope.jsonObject in the browser:

[image]

This is a menu creator:

```
function showDefaultMenu(menu,iterator){
            angular.forEach(menu, function(value, key){
                console.log(key);
                $('#myTree').append(
                    "<div class='col-md-12 col-xs-12'>" +
                    "<input type='checkbox' id='"+key+"' value='"+key+"' style='position: inherit;margin-left:"+iterator+"px'>"+key+
                    "</div>"
                );
                if(value.next !== undefined){
                    showDefaultMenu(value.next,iterator+20);
                }
            });
        }
        showDefaultMenu($scope.jsonObject,20);
```

This is a code in html:

```
<div id="myTree" class="col-md-12 col-xs-12" style="margin-top: 50px;border:1px solid black;">
</div>
<div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12" style="margin-top: 10px;" >
     <input type="button" ng-click="constructNewMenu()" class="button btn-xs btn-info" value="Create Menu" />
</div>
```

This is a `constructNewMenu()` used instead of `sortObject()`:

```
function constructNewMenu(){
     assistantConstructMenu($scope.jsonObject);
}

function assistantConstructMenu(menu){
    angular.forEach(menu, function(value, key){
        if ($('#' + key).is(':checked')) {
            if (key === "card") {
                $scope.sortMenu.push(menu);
            }
        }else{
           // I need delete object "no checked" from $scope.sortMenu
        }
        if(value.next !== undefined){
            assistantConstructMenu(value.next);
        }
    });
}
```

How to delete "no checked" menu, not knowing his level in the hierarchy of an object?

Comment: use delete of msdn.

Answer (score 0):

You could either do

```
delete $scope.sortMenu.Card.next.operations.next.history;
```

or just assign it to an empty `json` object

```
$scope.sortMenu.Card.next.operations.next.history = {};
```

P.S. Your Json Object looks complicated. The above code has possibilities of `can't get object of undefined` errors. May be you could get away by doing `null/undefined` checks.

Answer (score 0):

Use `delete` method :

```
if(key == "history"){
       delete  $scope.sortMenu.Card.next.operations.next.history;   
   }
```

for more information read [msdn delete](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2b2z052x(v=vs.94).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

use delete of msdn

```
if(key == "history"){
   // I need delete object "history" from $scope.sortMenu    
   delete $scope.sortMenu.Card.next.operations.next.history;
}
```

for more information read [msdn delete](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2b2z052x(v=vs.94).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

if(key == "history"){

```
   delete  $scope.sortMenu.Card.next.operations.next[key];
```

}